# Can I extend my sump pump outlet and dig it down in the ground?

Tags: water, drain, pvc, pump, sump

I attached an image of what I want, but essentially the water pools 6 feet from the house and ends up creating a swampy area for my dog to run though right out side the door.

Can I add a 45 degree and tilt it down run a 4 foot pipe, add another 45 and run another ~10 foot pipe, all graded slightly down towards the front of my house and essentially bury it under the ground and have it come out under my fence into a trench into the middle of my neighbors yard and mine?

Another option could be to do a 90 down, do like 1 inch then a another 90 just to get it in the ground a bit... and just do a 45 and run it to the corner of the fence under ground. I'm just worried to many joints will impede the flow.

So my question is, what is the drawback of extending this pipe that long if there is any, and am I going about this the right way?

Top Left corner is what it is now, purple pipe is what I want to add.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

There really aren't any hard-and-fast rules here as long as you don't work the pump too hard. Plenty of homes in my area have sump lines running all the way to the street gutter at 100 feet or more. You're right that you want to minimize bends, but a few won't hurt. The critical point is that the pipe is large enough. If you're talking about standard 1-1/4" pipe you're fine. Smooth-wall rigid pipe is best.